# Unable to debug .NET core projects in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio, .net-core, azure-service-fabric

I have a Service Fabric application with several services - some .NET core, some not. The target framework for all projects is .NET 4.6.2. Other members of my team are able to hit breakpoints in the core projects, but on my machine the symbols are never loaded. Breakpoints in the non-core projects are hit OK.

I have tried cleaning the solution, rebuilding, restarting Visual Studio and upgrading Visual Studio to 15.5.0 (from 15.3).

I am running a Debug build (x64).

I have also tried explicitly adding the output folders as symbol locations in the debugging settings.

Comment: This is similar question:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45769573/after-updating-to-vs2017-3-the-breakpoints-will-not-be-hit . Can you test recommendation from it?

Comment: @patutin - yes I tried that, but it has not resolved the issue

Comment: May be you turned something in your VS configuration. Please check Tools\Options\Debugging\General. Check that "Enable Just My Code" is turned off and inspect other properties.

Comment: @patutin. Yes I've checked that (and compared my debugging settings against my colleagues). I've tried adding a new asp.net core project (the others were created by other team members) and I am unable to debug into that. I think I will have to re-install VS as the next step

Answer (score 7):

Turned out it was the "Use Managed Compatibility Mode" setting (it was switched on for me). Turning that off allows debugging of .NET core Service Fabric services (it has no effect on normal .NET core projects).

Thanks patutin!

Answer (score 0):

In may case was Optimized Code turned on in Build section of Project